# Java Arraylist to Map speed comparison

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying convert an ArrayList to a Treemap, so I wrote a kind of a benchmark to compare various methods:

1) toMap in parallel stream

2) toMap in stream

3) forEach in stream

4) forEach in parallel stream

5) for loop

Everything works good if the ArrayList size is small (say 10,000), but when the size is big say a million, even after 9 mins its still running 'forEach Parallel Stream' method. I surrounded it with try catch but it was clean.

I know there will be a bit of overhead for creating new thread, but parallelStream uses threadPool so it should be low, right?

```
public class Set {
private String foo;
private int bar;

public Set(String foo, int bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
}

public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

public int getBar() {
    return bar;
}

public void setBar(int bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}

}
```

Main

```
public class Test {
TreeMap tr=new TreeMap();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.g();
}

public void g(){
    ArrayList<Set> ar=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        ar.add(new Set(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new Random().nextInt()));
    }
    long start;
    long end;
    System.out.println("Parallel toMap");
    start=System.nanoTime();
    tr.putAll(ar.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Set::getFoo, Set::getBar)));
    end=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end-start);

    tr=new TreeMap();
    System.out.println("non-Parallel toMap");
    start=System.nanoTime();
    tr.putAll(ar.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Set::getFoo, Set::getBar)));
    end=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end-start);

    tr=new TreeMap();
    System.out.println("non-Parallel forEach");
    start=System.nanoTime();
    ar.stream().forEach(product -> {
            tr.put(product.getFoo(), product.getBar());
        });
    end=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end-start);

    tr=new TreeMap();
    System.out.println("Parallel forEach");
    start=System.nanoTime();
//HANGS SOMEWHERE HERE
    ar.parallelStream().forEach(product -> {
        try {
            tr.put(product.getFoo(), product.getBar());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        });
    end=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end-start);

    tr=new TreeMap();
    System.out.println("non-Parallel loop");
    start=System.nanoTime();
    for(Set product:ar)
        tr.put(product.getFoo(), product.getBar());

    end=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end-start);
    }
}
```

the output for size 10_000 is as follows

```
Parallel toMap
130793206
non-Parallel toMap
21729202
non-Parallel forEach
7601349
Parallel forEach
3233395
non-Parallel loop
9744039
```

'for loop' is the slowest as expected

'paralled forEach' is faster than 'non-parallel forEach' as expected

'parallel toMap' is slower than 'non-parallel to map' by 5X?? what? Intel turbo boost at play?

back to the point why does 'forEach in parallel steam' fail when the arraylist list is big?

running i7 2670QM, so the threadPool size should be 8

Comment: ArrayList uses linear approach. i.e. each time it have to iterate the entire objects. where as map uses hashing mechanism so it will only search the objects having same hashcode.

Comment: yes, but how is it related to the code failing?

Answer (score 1):

`TreeMap` is not thread-safe. Therefore, when using it from multiple threads, all bets are off. You can get an infinite loop in `HashMap`. Presumably `TreeMap` behaves pretty badly in some manner.

(On benchmarking: Because of the way JVMs "warm up", you should start a new process for each test. Also run the test a number of times in a row within the one process.)

Comment: agreed that `TreeMap` is not thread-safe, but the question is why does it work when the size is 10,000 but fails when the size is 1 million?

Comment: @pallavt Presumably because there is more opportunity for things to go wrong in a million tries than 10,000. Also HotSpot tends to go around loops thousands of times before starting to compile it.